# Is there a way to tell if my application is causing high CPU usage?

Tags: flash, air

I've written an AIR application and I would like to know if there is a way to see how much CPU usage it is using from within the application (like a Flash API).

I know you can go Task Manager or Activity Monitor and view the CPU usage but that only works for me as the owner of the application. If someone else is using my application I want to be able to let them check or view the CPU usage within the app rather than ask them to launch an external operating system program which might be a support ticket and long drawn out process in and of itself.

Comment: Do you know about Hi-ReS-Stats? Used to use it before Scout. It's code in the app. It shows fps and memory usage. You can see if you're getting desired fps and also see how much memory is used and memory leaks.

Comment: I've used it before but I'm hoping there's a specific API available. If the frames drops below what I'd like then am I using more than 100% CPU? That could be due to external application using resources or it could be due to an activity in my app. I'd like to know resting CPU usage.